# How much life can I gain attacking someone who can't fall under 1 hp with lifelink creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

**Context :**

My friend played [Worship](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorship%5d), it states:

> If you control a creature, damage that would reduce your life total to less than 1 reduces it to 1 instead.

**Question :**

If I attack him with a 4/4 creature with lifelink while he already has 1HP will I still gain 4 HPs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The damage is still dealt fully, even though [Worship](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorship%5d) makes it so your life total can't go under 1. This means you gain the full 4 life from the lifelink creature.

Source: Gatherer rulings

> 10/4/2004 It reduces your life total to 1, not the damage to 1.
>   10/4/2004 Worship does not prevent damage. It causes some damage to be
>   unable to lower your life total. So any damage rendered useless by
>   Worship was still dealt and is counted by effects that track the
>   amount of damage done to a player. In addition, Worship does not
>   prevent loss of life, so loss of life bypasses Worship.

Comment: Thx a lot for this usefull answer !

Comment: And reason for this is that attackers must assign damage equal to their power, and they deal the amount of damage they assigned. Effects such as Worship's modify or reduce the damage taken, but not the damage dealt.